# Yii create a new attribute in the model doesn't work

Tags: php, yii, cactiverecord

I need to create a new attribute in the model and something weird is happening:

this code, works fine:

```
class Person extends CActiveRecord {

   public $test = "xxx";

   public function getRandomToken() {
      $temp = $this->test;
      return $temp;
   }
```

this code, does not:

```
class Person extends CActiveRecord {

   public $test = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));

   public function getRandomToken() {
      $temp = $this->test;
      return $temp;
   }
```

why?
I get a blank page with the second code, with no errors.

I will need to use the random token from create view-page and I'm doing it in this way:

```
echo $model->getRandomToken();
```

Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to overwrite the contructor you can use this:

```
class Person extends CActiveRecord {

   public $test = null;

   public function getRandomToken() {
      if ($this->test == null){
        $this->test = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
      }
      $temp = $this->test;
      return $temp;
   }
```

Comment: That's a nice solution. Thank you! But, do you have an idea of why my code wasn't working?

Comment: The functions md5, uniqid and rand as pointed out by Barry are not accessible at the attribute declaration level. I am not sure why you are not seeing an error, but my guess is you should check your PHP error_reporting level. The recommended level for dev is: E_ALL | E_STRICT. Accept the answer if it was helpfull. OR check your log file for errors.

Comment: Thank you. I would love to accept the answer but i have not much reputation to do that. If you vote the question i might reach 15 points, but not sure.! sorry about that. I will do it as soon as i can anyway

Answer (score 5):

You cannot assign a function result as value. It must be a constant. Assign the function value in the constructor

```
public $test = '';

function __construct() {
    $this->test = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
}
```

Comment: I didn't know I could have changed the constructor so easily. Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell me why the class only accepts constants and not functions results please?

Comment: It cannot be done in PHP, see [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

Comment: Note that when overwritting a constructor, you have to make sure to pass all the required parameters to the parent class if any. The exmaple above will only work if your parent class does not take any parameters.